# Error while processing specific images - Grayscale converter Visual C++ UWP

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, visual-c++, uwp

I created a Universal Windows App with Visual C++ just for the sake of learning. The project consists in a tool that creates a grayscale copy of given image file chosen by the user.

In many cases the app runs correctly like in this case:
[image: Grayscale Converter working properly]

But there are some cases in which does not:
[image]

#### Observations and behavior

- The application executes in any case with no runtime errors.
- I've noticed that this problem affects only specific images, in the sense that if an image fails it will *always* fail, if not it will *never* fail. For example, the image in the first screenshot always completed correctly, the second one always failed.
- I would exclude the possibility of something related to file formats, as several `.png`, `.jpg` and `.jpeg` work.
- I would exclude problems related to how the source image is captured and saved, as I tested images taken from the same device, same resolution and with almost identical file size (~6MB) but that have different outcomes.

#### The code

Here is the relevant portion of my project that handles the image processing:

```
void MainPage::ConvertPicture()
{

    RandomAccessStreamReference^ StreamFromFile = 
        RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromFile(SelectedImageFile);

    // From Stream create BitmapDecoder.
    create_task(StreamFromFile->OpenReadAsync())
       .then([this](IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^ fileStream)
    {
        BitmapDecoder^ ImageDecoder;

        // From BitmapDecoder create BitmapFrame.
        create_task(ImageDecoder->CreateAsync(fileStream))
            .then([this](BitmapDecoder^ decoder)
        {

            create_task(decoder->GetFrameAsync(0)).then([this](BitmapFrame^ BitFrame) 
            {
                // Get Width, Height and Center coordinates of the image.
                width = BitFrame->PixelWidth;
                height = BitFrame->PixelHeight;

                // From BitmapFrame create PixelDataProvider.
                create_task(BitFrame->GetPixelDataAsync()).then([this](PixelDataProvider^ pixelProvider)
                {
                    // Get array of pixels.
                    SourcePixels = pixelProvider->DetachPixelData();

                    // Create the WriteableBitmap. 
                    bitmap = ref new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

                    // Set the bitmap to the Image element.
                    ModifiedImage->Source = bitmap;

                    // Get access to the pixels.
                    IBuffer^ buffer = bitmap->PixelBuffer;

                    // Obtain IBufferByteAccess.
                    ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> pBufferByteAccess;
                    ComPtr<IUnknown> pBuffer((IUnknown*)buffer);
                    pBuffer.As(&pBufferByteAccess);

                    // Get pointer to pixel bytes.
                    pBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&DestinationPixels);

                    for (int yDestination = 0; yDestination < height; yDestination++)
                    {
                        for (int xDestination = 0; xDestination < width; xDestination++)
                        {
                            // Calculate the indexes.
                            // Since pixels won't be moved they share the same
                            // origins yDestination and xDestination.
                            int iDst = 4 * (yDestination * width + xDestination);
                            int iSrc = 4 * (yDestination * width + xDestination);

                            // Generate grayscale pixel color based on average RGB.
                            byte AveragePixel = (byte)((SourcePixels[iSrc++] + 
                            SourcePixels[iSrc++] + SourcePixels[iSrc++]) / 3);
                        
                            // Transfer the pixel bytes.
                            // Alpha channel is unchanged.
                            DestinationPixels[iDst++] = AveragePixel;       // Blue
                            DestinationPixels[iDst++] = AveragePixel;       // Green
                            DestinationPixels[iDst++] = AveragePixel;       // Red
                            DestinationPixels[iDst] = SourcePixels[iSrc];   // Alpha channel
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

If you want to see more code or to try out my project you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/MateiRadu/grayscale-converter).

So my question is

#### What could the problem be?

Given that I'm a novice with Visual C++ I haven't been able to find anything relevant during debug and I am now stuck.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the `BitmapPixelFormat` of the source BitmapFrame.

Comment: You're assuming that the format of the source image is 24 bit RGB. Certain images, like PNGs, have an alpha channel in ARGB 32 bit format.

Comment: @Clemens the value of BitmapPixelFormat is the same in all cases, both functioning and non functioning images.

Comment: @DecadeMoon the app processes some PNGs and in the cose I do consider an alpha channel.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226240.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was ignoring the `Exif` properties of the images, so in certain cases the width and height got inverted in the process.

> In order to retrieve the correct bitmap pixel width and height, the application should read the OrientedPixelWidth and OrientedPixelHeight properties, instead of the PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties. - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226192.aspx)

So I fixed as follows:

```
// Get Width, Height and Center coordinates of the image.
width = BitFrame->OrientedPixelWidth;
height = BitFrame->OrientedPixelHeight;
```

Now it works!
[image: Working]